# How to fix R.string errors when converting to library with ADT14+ android

Tags: android, android-library, acra

I am trying to convert my application project to library, I am getting errors like

```
resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title,

The value for annotation attribute ReportsCrashes.resDialogTitle must be a constant expression
```

They are used in ACRA header

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "--", mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG, mailTo = "--", customReportContent = {
        ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
        ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
        ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT }
// resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional, displayed as soon as
// the crash occurs, before collecting data which can take a few seconds
        resDialogText = getString(R.string.crash_dialog_text),
        resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, // optional.
// default
// is
// a
// warning
// sign
//resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your
// application name
resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. when
// defined, adds
// a user text
// field input
// with this
// text resource
// as a label
resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast // optional. displays a Toast
// message when the user
// accepts to send a report.
)
public class MainAppClass extends Application {

    private static MainAppClass singleton;
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

In ACRA, since ADT 14, [R fields are not constants in library project](https://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=134). 2 solutions:

1. Declare R.string.crash_dialog_text in the app that uses library
2. You can [dynamically](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#dynamic-configuration) set these with ACRA.getConfig():

> The method ACRA.getConfig() returns an ACRAConfiguration object which provides a setter for each @ReportsCrashes configuration item.

eg:

```
    ACRA.getConfig().setResDialogText(R.string.crash_dialog_text);
```

Remember to call **ACRA.init(this);** in your onCreate() method.

You can set all the fields you need this way. Check [here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/ACRAConfiguration.java).

Comment: You need Context to use getString(). You can use you Activity's context.

Comment: can you try, it didnt work for me beacuse the text ReportCrashes i above the class block {}

Comment: It is used with Application Class, posted the top relevant portion.  Dear Melquiades I cannot put the getString etc as it is not in class body

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078016/android-library-projects-could-not-be-used-with-acra-due-to-their-resources-iden. Just set the Annotation values to 0, then set those dynamic configs before/after calling init. Worth noting, the ACRA source shows the next version will release an init method that takes the Dynamic configs: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/ACRA.java#L135